# Pass Soket.io to Express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I would use socket.io in my routes file.

I have found multiple methods but no one worked for me.

Now I'm trying this [solution](https://gist.github.com/laterbreh/5d7bdf03258152c95b8d)

```
var http = require("http");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = process.env.app_port || 8080; // set our port
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var server = app.listen(port);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var routerProj = require("./routes/routes")(io);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,*");
  next();
});
var config = {
      XXX
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


var serviceAccount = require("./ServiceAcountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://datatable-18f93.firebaseio.com"
});
app.use("/v1", routerProj);
//Create HTTP server and listen on port 8000 for requests

// Print URL for accessing server
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("a user is connected");
});
```

Routes.js

```
var express = require("express"); // call express
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
module.exports = function (io) {

  /*router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log('User has connected to Index');
    });
  });*/
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  io.on('save-message', function (socket) {
    console.log('User has connected to Index');
  });
});
  router
    .route("/")
    .get(function (req, res, err) {

      // Get a database reference to our posts
      var db = admin.database();
      var ref = db.ref("/");

      // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
      ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
        var list = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function (elem) {
          list.push(elem.val());
        })
        list = JSON.stringify(list);
        //list = JSON.parse(list)

        //console.log(JSON.stringify(list))

        res.send(list);


      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        res.status(500).send(errorObject.code);
      });
    });

  router
    .route("/")
    .post(function (req, res, err) {
      console.log(req.body);
      // Get a database reference to our posts
      var db = admin.database();
      var ref = db.ref("/");

      // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
      ref.push(
        {
          "text": req.body.text
        }

      );

    });
  return router
}
```

sockets are working in my server.js file , in console I get the message :"a user is connected" when I run my angular app.

But in my browser I run `http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1`in router.js console.log is not working, so sockets is not getting passed.

I have tried to emit an event :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.emit('save-message', { room: "hello" });
  }
```

In my **router.js** :

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  io.on('save-message', function (socket) {
    console.log('User has connected to Index');
  });
});
```

console.log don't print anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the socket will only have one connection event because it is being passed as it is created and connected to. Try listening for another event emitted by the client to the router instead. Are you getting the `a user is connected` log when you browse `http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1`?

Comment: No I'm getting that when I open my angular app : localhost:4200

Comment: You never want to add an event handler like `io.on('connection', ...)` in a `router.use()` middleware.  That will pile up event handlers forever, adding a new one on every single http request to your server, eventually having tens of thousands of event handlers registered.  That is definitely not the correct way to do things.  For us to help you, we need to know more about what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are also using 2 module.exports in the Router.js

Comment: I have updated my post. What I would is to listen from my routes.js to events emited in my client side.

Comment: Does the rest of the router code work like expected?

Comment: no, post route is not sending data to client

Comment: It looks like you're not responding to the request at all. I would either send the data as `res.send(data-to-send)` or `res.json(data-to-send)`. Or something along your needs. I would also recommend chaining your  method calls `router.route('/').get(handle-get).post(handle-post);`.